Do Tektro brake hoses (for m275 especially) have multiple identifiable layers?
I have some Tektro m275 hydraulic breaks where the gear cable has ground-down a surprising amount of rubber/plastic from my brake hose.
I have never seen the cross-section of these hoses and I am wondering if these hoses typically have multiple identifiable layers so that as long as I can't see any 2nd or 3rd layer then the damage should be of less concern than otherwise.
If you have knowledge about this specific model, or Tektro brakes in general it is the best, but info like "all the hoses I have seen have different layers" or "it's 50/50" is also useful. There are no markings on the hoses.
Replacing is of course the safest option, but please stick to the question at hand.

Some hoses have no identifiable layers eg. some cheaper Magura hoses. Some have some fabric layer. There are also braided hoses with a metal woven layer. You won't know what you have unless you cut a cross section to examine.

@Noise Thanks, narrowed down the question since you answered the generall question right there!

The Tektro M275 is the cheapest hydraulic brake with a brand name. Different years can have different hoses, further complicating matters.

Is it worth adding a photo of the damage ?

@Criggie It would be "fun" to show, but I have put on some tape that I'm reluctant to put on again. It's worse than most would expect and I'd probably just get tons of "that has to be replaced"-answers witouth getting any answers to the actuall question.

Note with Tektro/TRP you can just use a coupler to replace from the damaged section on, if for some reason doing a full replacement was prohibitive, like if it saves you a motor drop. I see that the question is trying to be specific about whether there are layers or no, but the reason most would frame challenge that is even if there are layers, you can't just jump to conclusions about which are protective vs structural.

@NathanKnutson  Thx for the tip. I'll probably replace the entire unit when I can as it has a lazy piston as well. If you proivde a link to an example of that "thing", I could have a look at it. I'm guessing inserting some "coupuling-device" where the damage is.. but I'm not used to fixing this kind of stuff so probably not worth the time/money for me.

https://trpcycling.com/products/hose-coupler Note there are now two sizes, 5.5 and 5mm.

As always, brakes are safety critical and I would recommend erring on the side of caution. That said, most brake hoses that I've seen have multiple layers (although as noted in the comments under your question, some do not). Usually there's three main components:

An inner layer that prevents the fluid from leaking out.
A woven layer which handles structural integrity under pressure.
An outer sheath which protects the textile from abrasion, dirt, and solvents.

With Shimano hoses at least, these are a translucent plastic tube, an off-white/amber weave (much like a Chinese finger trap), and a black tube respectively. I would reckon that as long as you can't see the woven layer (either directly seeing it or by the presence of loose fibers), you should still be alright. Definitely inspect the cut carefully though and exercise some critical thinking. The outer sheath probably isn't very thick to begin with, so if the cut is deeper than 0.5mm (see next paragraph), I'd suspect that the textile layer has already been reached or that the hose doesn't have distinct visible layers to begin with. In either case, the hose is probably unsafe to continue using with that deep of a cut.
To put some numbers on that previous paragraph, this post reports that your hose has an inner diameter of 2.5mm and an outer diameter of 5.5mm. That leaves you with 1.5mm of wall thickness total. It's probably reasonable to assume that the three layers have similar thicknesses, so yeah, if the cut is any deeper than 0.5mm (!), you have some cause for concern.
If possible, I'd be tempted to slide some heatshrink tubing over the area to reinforce the cut (by undoing the hydraulic cutting at the lever or caliper and sliding the tubing over the end. Would require a brake bleed afterwards). Not really as structural support mind you--more to serve as that protective sheath. Otherwise, a spiral wrap of electrical tape would also be helpful as an alternative.
